# python number guessing

Tags: python

I am not understanding this, it says there is a syntax error  at the end of the word correct.

```
x=int(raw_input("Number: ")) <--/error/
y=385
if x == y:
    print("correct")
if x < y:
    print("too low")
if x > y:
    print("too high")
```

New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
    x=int(raw_input("Number: "))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Though the input is 458.

Comment: Which editor did you use to edit/save the file? Could you check whether the opening double-quote is the same as the closing one?

Comment: Run `python -tt yourscript.py` to check for indentation errors.

Comment: Its now an undefined error.

Comment: Either install Python 2.7, or use valid Python 3; with `input`instead of `raw_input` and `print(foo)` instead of `print foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabbing vs spaces issue? It's most likely indentation. Use `python -tt` at the top of the file to check. Or else you can run it in the command line. Having it in the file is handier for me, don't have to worry about it then. Eg, I use this in every file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
```

Otherwise it's a version issue and then you simply use parenthesis' and use print as  a function. `print("example")`. However `raw_input` works, so try your indentation.

---

EDIT: I see your edit and `raw_input` doesn't work, most likely you are using a newer version of Python, Python3, so `print` is now a function and you can't use `raw_input`. So as I said, try `print("example")` and change use from `raw_input`

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python3 and `print` was made into a function